# Time efficient way to implement Multi-Armed-Bandits?

Tags: performance, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I'm doing a research on Multi-Armed Bandit (MAB) problem with approx. 1 million arms. In contrast, the number of iterations is of course much larger, about 10-20 million.

Most MAB-algorithms require an argmax operator (argmax of the action space) that has to be executed in each iteration in order to select the current arm (which maximizes a given selection criterion). Regardless of the chosen programming language for implementation, this procedure/ this argmax operator over the entire action space (1 million arms) is very time-consuming.

Does anyone have some ideas on how to implement MAB algorithms in a time-efficient way?

Comment: Which algorithm(s) are you trying? (UCB1? EXP3?) What values are being returned when you try an arm? (integer, real) Are there any properties you can take advantage of with regard to the values of the unsampled arms? (eg If they stay ordered, then sort them and then you only need to evaluate the first one.) That is, lots of possibilities, but more information is needed to help.

Comment: Primarily, it is about UCB1. The returned values are real numbers.
In the first 1 million runs, each arm must be selected at least once before any arm is selected twice. Therefore no argmax operator is necessary in these first 1 m runs.
Sorting the arms according to their value is one idea, however after selecting an arm and updating its value, this arm must be put back in the correct order / correct position of the list of sorted arms. This may take less time, but the question remains: Are there better/other ideas? or are there suggestions on how I can implement this idea? priority queues?

Answer (score 0):

In UCB1 there are two terms that determine which arm is selected next - the average reward, and the confidence bound.

```
average + sqrt(2 ln N / n_i)
```

Setting aside the average reward thus far, the second term depends on the total number of samples (N), which is the same for all arms, and the total samples of a given arm (n_i). Thus, for all arms that have been sampled the same number of times, the second term will be the same.

A simple approach would be to bucket arms by the number of samples performed. Then, within each bucket, you can sort by reward (high to low). When you want to decide which arm to sample next, you just check the arm with the highest payoff in each bucket and then choose the bucket with the highest value (from the UCB equation) to sample next. You won't need to test more than the first entry from each bucket.

There are further improvements that can be done on top of this, but this will be significantly better than iterating over all arms at each time step.